# How to route requests to Lambda from ECS so that all the extra requests are handled by Lambda in the case of unpredictable traffic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53

I want to design a AWS solution where a service would run on ECS.
The service has to be fully functioning if the ECS is down and should also be able to handle unpredictable spikes in requests.

I have come up with a solution where we use ECS as the primary service and lambda as secondary.
All the requests will be served through ECS but in cases like extra traffic/ECS unavailable we send the requests to lambda for processing. The solution should also be able to route all the traffic back to ECS when its available or when the traffic subsides.

I am thinking of using Route 53 weighted-rules with Cloudwatch alarm health checks to adjust the weights for routing. The problem is Route53 only allows targets like ELB, API Gateway, Cloudfront etc. It is not allowing me to route directly to lambda. Is there any way I can achieve this? Also is there any better way to designing such a solution.

Comment: is there already a load balancer?  you can put lambda behind that, and weight traffic between different targets but I don't think it would work with auto failover

Comment: There is not. Even with a load balancer we can't achieve smart failovers that has traffic routed back to ECS when the spike dies or ECS is available.

Comment: You can't route directly to Lambda because Lambda doesn't support having custom domain names routed directly to it. You have to configure either an Application Load Balancer, or an API Gateway in front of Lambda, and point your Route53 domain at that.

Comment: Thanks. Went ahead with having an API gateway in front of lambda.

Answer (score 0):

In order to route traffic to Lambda directly, you can use the Lambda function URL:

[image: Route53 setting]

and create CNAME record with weighted policy.